# Is there HR Schema default in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle-database

I just installed Oracle 19c and it was successful 
but it didn't show any password management as  in 11g to unlock HR and other schemas.
 So I was wondering whether there is HR Schema in Oracle 19c.
 if it is there then how to unlock it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer  **YES THERE IS**. in oracle 19c there will not be a password management  screen shown as in 11g after installation .

But you can unlock the hr schema in oracle by using  come codes in command prompt "**CMD"** .

Oracle 19c is little bit tricky  to get hr schema, but  u can follow the steps  described in [This blog](http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-unlock-hr-user-in-oracle-database-18c-by-manish-sharma/#.W6tJkWgzbIV)  which is very easy